# Why is this jQuery giving me an "NaN"?

Tags: jquery, floating-point

I could swear this code was working earlier, but now it's not, and hasn't changed, so:

I have 1..5 boxes that will have money values in them (such as 10.00 or blank). The totals are computed and then displayed in a "grand total" box like so:

```
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});
```

If I enter a "50" into the first box, and blur (exit), it changes to "50.00" (as it should). But "boxGrandTotal" displays "NaN" Why?

Note: The five "boxAmount" input texts have the CSS class "amountbox" assigned/attached to them.

### UPDATE

It turns out the ID of box3 had some stuff appended to it, and it wasn't being floatified, thus causing this whole mess. I found out by alerting every value, and seeing that box3 was NaN.

Comment: Did you try console.log()-ing `amount1-5`?

Comment: Can you post your html code in order to recreate your issue?

Comment: Do the other boxes perhaps have non-parseable values? If any of `amount1` through `amount5` is `NaN`, then `grandtotal` will be `NaN` as well.

Comment: Try changing your condition `!= ''` to `!= null`...thank me later :)

Comment: @TedHopp is right. The only time I could recreate having a NaN is when I only had 4 input fields instead of 5. Here is a fiddle showing it working properly (in what I assume your code is). http://jsfiddle.net/yq3a6234/

Comment: was mentioned some time ago in another on of your posts that would need to check for NaN on all these values.. If user has fat fingers and slips a non numeric character in there will fail

Comment: @Hackerman - As far as I know, jQuery's `.val()` function will never return `null` for `input` elements.

Comment: I made a sample fiddle and it is working fine, with the code and hints provided by the OP: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9kxxx3Lr/

Comment: @Hackerman: I had it as null originally, and somebody advised the new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal+'').toFixed(2));
```

try this.

also make sure the the fields you check for empty string `''` are not null